# PostgreSQL function numeric type error

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, stored-functions

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL. The function works when I use `float`, but when I try to change the `float`s to `numeric` I get an error:

```
ERROR: cannot change return type of existing function
SQL state: 42P13
Detail: Row type defined by OUT parameters is different.
Hint: Use DROP FUNCTION percent_grades(text) first.
```

I don't really know what that means, but I don't think that I'd need to do anything other than `CAST` to change the `type`.

My function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION percent_grades(text)
RETURNS TABLE(grade text, percent float)
AS
  $$
    DECLARE percent_total float;
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
        SELECT psa_grade_name, 
               SUM(psa_amount) / CAST(total_cards($1) AS float) AS percent_total
        FROM psa_pop_view
        WHERE psa_card = $1
        GROUP BY psa_grade_name
        ORDER BY psa_grade_name;
    END;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to replace the `float`s with `numeric(5, 4)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

a `create or replace` statement cannot change the signature of a function. As the error says, you must first drop the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION percent_grades(text);
```

And only then re-create it with the right signature:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION percent_grades(text)
RETURNS TABLE(grade text, percent numeric(5,4))
AS
  $$
    DECLARE percent_total float;
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
        SELECT psa_grade_name, 
               SUM(psa_amount) / CAST(total_cards($1) AS float) AS percent_total
        FROM psa_pop_view
        WHERE psa_card = $1
        GROUP BY psa_grade_name
        ORDER BY psa_grade_name;
    END;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: why REPLACE  does not work?! ))